# cal command not working

Tags: command-line, bash, calendar

I am trying to access calendar by "cal" command in terminal but there is error message.

```
hetz@hetz-Lappy:~$ cal
bash: cal: command not found
```

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: I have upgraded from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS recently.

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend first installing `command-not-found` to help with errors like this:

```
sudo apt install command-not-found
```

Then open a new terminal to ensure its features will be available within it.

Now when you try to run `cal`, you will get an more useful error message which will tell you which package to install:

```
Command 'cal' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install ncal
```

Comment: Running zsh, command-not-found does not appear to work -- still get the same command not found

Comment: @OskarAustegard For Zsh, you need to add the `command_not_found_handle` function to `.zshrc` (see my [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1444625/806294) for an example).

Answer (score 2):

Install the `ncal` package:

```
sudo apt install ncal
```

If you have `command-not-found` installed and enabled (which it is by default in Bash) you should get a suggestion to install the package. If you use Zsh, copy these lines from `/etc/bash.bashrc` to your `.zshrc` (or enable a relevant plugin for your Zsh framework):

```
# if the command-not-found package is installed, use it
if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found -o -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
    function command_not_found_handle {
        # check because c-n-f could've been removed in the meantime
        if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
           /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1"
           return $?
        elif [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
           /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1"
           return $?
        else
           printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" >&2
           return 127
        fi
    }
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for some reason **cal** is no more present on the distribution installation, what I recommend is to install **fcal** as following:

`snap install fcal` - Must run it as a root user

After this you will have the command **fcal** avaible, it will act like **cal** (it's not but it's kind of work around).